# Winforms - Replace a ConnectionString at runtime

Tags: .net, winforms, configuration, connection-string

I'd like to allow my users to switch between different databases on the login page at runtime.

I currently have the ConnectionString stored in my App Settings file and all the datasets refer to this setting.

I have tried modifying this setting at runtime, but this seems impossible.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just have a second connection string in your config file?  What sort of data access code have you got setup?

Comment: all my datasets have their connectionstring as MyConnectionString (stored in app.setting)

Comment: Is your problem that all your datasets are individually accessing the value from the config file?  If it is then why not create a single piece of code responsible for returning the connection string to your datasets, then have that code read the appropriate connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the code to pick up the connection string from disk by calling [`ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) prior to fetching the connection string:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the database encrypted?

If it's not something that requires a large amount of privacy, you can store the connection string on a per-user basis.

For example:

```
System.Properties.Default.MyConnectionString = "Blah";
System.Properties.Default.Save();
```

or

```
string myConnectionString = System.Properties.Default.MyConnectionString;
```

EDIT:  These can originally be set in VS by going to Project -> Properties -> Settings and make sure you put them in "User" Scope  (Application Scope is read-only during runtime unless I'm mistaken).

EDIT2:  Regarding comment below:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
//Set from a normal String saved in user's settings
myConnection.ConnectionString = System.Properties.Default.MyConnectionString; 
myConnection.Open();
```

Comment: Connection Strings are restricted to Application Scope :-( Thanks though

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you can use the 'String' type though.

Comment: the `connectiostring` in `properties.default` is readonly, how is possible to change it?